# Compare Values in multiple arrays

Tags: php, curl

I've been stuck on trying to figure this out for a few hours now.

I'm using cURL and PHP to get data from an API and then display that data in a table. I have my table setup to show start position of a race, where they finished, the name of the person, and how far behind they finished.

In my column for how far behind they finished the API doesn't take into account that somebody might not complete all the laps in the race. For example 2nd place finished 4.285 seconds behind the leader, but 14th place finished 0.929 behind the leader because they were a lap behind and in between the leader and second place.

I'm trying to figure out how to find the first position that didn't complete all the laps (this could be a different position for every race) and then every position after the first person a lap behind. If that makes sense.

Below is the API response and I'm trying to compare data from the ResultTime key.

```
{
    "RequestValid": 1,
    "ItemsReturned": 1,
    "Classes": [
        {
            "Races": [
                {
                    "RaceName": "Feature",
                    "RaceType": "Feature",
                    "RaceOrder": 1,
                    "RaceLevel": "A",
                    "RaceLaps": 50,
                    "RaceTime": "00:27:39.532",
                    "RacePresenter": "",
                    "RaceNotes": "",
                    "RaceStatus": "Completed",
                    "Results": [
                        {
                            "ResultPlace": 1,
                            "ResultStart": 4,
                            "ResultTime": "1659.532",
                            "ResultCarNum": "49",
                            "ResultDNF": 0,
                            "ResultDNS": 0,
                            "ResultDQ": 0,
                        },
                        {
                            "ResultPlace": 2,
                            "ResultStart": 2,
                            "ResultTime": "1663.817",
                            "ResultCarNum": "1",
                            "ResultDNF": 0,
                            "ResultDNS": 0,
                            "ResultDQ": 0,
                        },
                        {
                            "ResultPlace": 3,
                            "ResultStart": 7,
                            "ResultTime": "1664.368",
                            "ResultCarNum": "28",
                            "ResultDNF": 0,
                            "ResultDNS": 0,
                            "ResultDQ": 0,
                        },
                        {
                            "ResultPlace": 4,
                            "ResultStart": 13,
                            "ResultTime": "1664.544",
                            "ResultCarNum": "1T",
                            "ResultDNF": 0,
                            "ResultDNS": 0,
                            "ResultDQ": 0,
                        },
                        {
                            "ResultPlace": 5,
                            "ResultStart": 1,
                            "ResultTime": "1665.218",
                            "ResultCarNum": "7",
                            "ResultDNF": 0,
                            "ResultDNS": 0,
                            "ResultDQ": 0,
                        },
                        {
                            "ResultPlace": 6,
                            "ResultStart": 8,
                            "ResultTime": "1666.842",
                            "ResultCarNum": "01",
                            "ResultDNF": 0,
                            "ResultDNS": 0,
                            "ResultDQ": 0,
                        },
                        {
                            "ResultPlace": 7,
                            "ResultStart": 10,
                            "ResultTime": "1668.640",
                            "ResultCarNum": "14",
                            "ResultDNF": 0,
                            "ResultDNS": 0,
                            "ResultDQ": 0,
                        },
                        {
                            "ResultPlace": 8,
                            "ResultStart": 15,
                            "ResultTime": "1670.214",
                            "ResultCarNum": "8",
                            "ResultDNF": 0,
                            "ResultDNS": 0,
                            "ResultDQ": 0,
                        },
                        {
                            "ResultPlace": 9,
                            "ResultStart": 21,
                            "ResultTime": "1672.037",
                            "ResultCarNum": "111V",
                            "ResultDNF": 0,
                            "ResultDNS": 0,
                            "ResultDQ": 0,
                        },
                        {
                            "ResultPlace": 10,
                            "ResultStart": 9,
                            "ResultTime": "1674.171",
                            "ResultCarNum": "44",
                            "ResultDNF": 0,
                            "ResultDNS": 0,
                            "ResultDQ": 0,
                        },
                        {
                            "ResultPlace": 11,
                            "ResultStart": 17,
                            "ResultTime": "1674.247",
                            "ResultCarNum": "16",
                            "ResultDNF": 0,
                            "ResultDNS": 0,
                            "ResultDQ": 0,
                        },
                        {
                            "ResultPlace": 12,
                            "ResultStart": 19,
                            "ResultTime": "1674.732",
                            "ResultCarNum": "72",
                            "ResultDNF": 0,
                            "ResultDNS": 0,
                            "ResultDQ": 0,
                        },
                        {
                            "ResultPlace": 13,
                            "ResultStart": 23,
                            "ResultTime": "1675.363",
                            "ResultCarNum": "99B",
                            "ResultDNF": 0,
                            "ResultDNS": 0,
                            "ResultDQ": 0,
                        },
                        {
                            "ResultPlace": 14,
                            "ResultStart": 16,
                            "ResultTime": "1660.461",
                            "ResultCarNum": "10",
                            "ResultDNF": 0,
                            "ResultDNS": 0,
                            "ResultDQ": 0,
                        },
                        {
                            "ResultPlace": 15,
                            "ResultStart": 24,
                            "ResultTime": "1663.480",
                            "ResultCarNum": "B1",
                            "ResultDNF": 0,
                            "ResultDNS": 0,
                            "ResultDQ": 0,
                        },
                        {
                            "ResultPlace": 16,
                            "ResultStart": 22,
                            "ResultTime": "1666.772",
                            "ResultCarNum": "7R",
                            "ResultDNF": 0,
                            "ResultDNS": 0,
                            "ResultDQ": 0,
                        },
                        {
                            "ResultPlace": 17,
                            "ResultStart": 6,
                            "ResultTime": "1669.867",
                            "ResultCarNum": "20",
                            "ResultDNF": 0,
                            "ResultDNS": 0,
                            "ResultDQ": 0,
                        },
                        {
                            "ResultPlace": 18,
                            "ResultStart": 14,
                            "ResultTime": "1673.277",
                            "ResultCarNum": "111",
                            "ResultDNF": 0,
                            "ResultDNS": 0,
                            "ResultDQ": 0,
                        },
                        {
                            "ResultPlace": 19,
                            "ResultStart": 12,
                            "ResultTime": "1387.076",
                            "ResultCarNum": "19R",
                            "ResultDNF": 0,
                            "ResultDNS": 0,
                            "ResultDQ": 0,
                        },
                        {
                            "ResultPlace": 20,
                            "ResultStart": 20,
                            "ResultTime": "1353.423",
                            "ResultCarNum": "0H",
                            "ResultDNF": 0,
                            "ResultDNS": 0,
                            "ResultDQ": 0,
                        },
                        {
                            "ResultPlace": 21,
                            "ResultStart": 5,
                            "ResultTime": "1340.342",
                            "ResultCarNum": "11",
                            "ResultDNF": 0,
                            "ResultDNS": 0,
                            "ResultDQ": 0,
                        },
                        {
                            "ResultPlace": 22,
                            "ResultStart": 11,
                            "ResultTime": "1284.877",
                            "ResultCarNum": "76",
                            "ResultDNF": 0,
                            "ResultDNS": 0,
                            "ResultDQ": 0,
                        },
                        {
                            "ResultPlace": 23,
                            "ResultStart": 3,
                            "ResultTime": "962.947",
                            "ResultCarNum": "39",
                            "ResultDNF": 0,
                            "ResultDNS": 0,
                            "ResultDQ": 0,
                        },
                        {
                            "ResultPlace": 24,
                            "ResultStart": 18,
                            "ResultTime": "239.697",
                            "ResultCarNum": "23B",
                            "ResultDNF": 0,
                            "ResultDNS": 0,
                            "ResultDQ": 0,
                        },
                        {
                            "ResultPlace": 25,
                            "ResultStart": 25,
                            "ResultTime": "156.942",
                            "ResultCarNum": "42",
                            "ResultDNF": 0,
                            "ResultDNS": 0,
                            "ResultDQ": 0,
                        }
                    ]
                },
        ]
}
```

UPDATE 2 to show code

```
foreach ($raceresults as $raceresult) {
//Checking if race has a time
    if ($raceresult['ResultTime'] == "0.000") {
        $racetime = "No Time";
        $laptimebehindpadded = "No Time";
    } else {
        //Getting Time of Race
        $racetime = $raceresult['ResultTime'];
        //Taking leaders overall time and subtracting each position to get time behind.
        $laptimebehind = $quicktime - $racetime;
        //Converting time behind to show 3 decimal places
        $laptimebehindpadded = sprintf('%0.3f', $laptimebehind);
    }
}

echo $laptimebehindpadded;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of your code.  You have a variable $quicktime that is not defined anywhere in the code you provided.  You also don't get any benefit from taking an existing array variable and assigning it to another variable with a different name ie.  `$racetime = $raceresult['ResultTime'];`

Comment: Perhaps it would help to clarify what you are actually trying to infer, other than as I've pointed out, anytime someone finished with a time that was < the time of the prior participant, this implies the participant was lapped.  Since these are results, does it also imply that the participant didn't finish the race?  I don't know what you hope to do with the information that someone was lapped, other than to show that they were lapped, and that their time was relative to being lapped some number of times, since the participants are already in their place order.

Answer (score 0):

Have a $priorResultTime = 0 and a $lapBehind = 0.  As you foreach() through the result array, compare $result['ResultTime'] with $priorResultTime.

```
$priorResultTime = 0;
$lapBehind = 0;

foreach(... as $result) {
  if ($result['ResultTime'] < $priorResultTime) {
      $lapBehind++;
  }
  $priorResultTime = $result['ResultTime'];
}
```

Your output can now take advantage of the $lapBehind variable, and indicate how many laps behind the leader a racer was, along with their relative time.

Comment: I think I'm following you for the most part. Currently I'm getting the $result['ResultTime'] from the array and then comparing the times between the 1st place time. I've put your code in place of that but I'm still just getting the $result['ResultTime'].

Comment: Would have to see your code, but this assumes that when you output whatever it is that you output, this new concept of lap would need to be introduced.  If you are subtracting 1st place time from racetime, then you would need to improve that output so rather than having "+xxx.xxx"  or whatever your show, if the participant was lapped ($lapBehind > 0)  then you would show "$lapBehind laps +xxx.xxx"

Comment: See update 2 for code without your edit.